# Error adding InventorySite to Quickbooks invoices in QBSDK 12

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml, qbfc

I have a QBFC application written in C# that runs automatically from the scheduler and, among other things, inserts invoices from a remote client into QB.

Recently, I upgraded it to add an "InventorySite" to invoice items for clients using QB's "Advanced Inventory" module. I upgraded to QBFC 12 at the same time.

The program now errors out when it attempts insert an invoice, saying the InventorySiteLocationRef element is unrecognized. All other functions work as usual.

The following is an excerpt from QBSDKLog.txt:

```
20130712.143859 I   736 QBSDKProcessRequest Application named 'IOS Briefcase Sync' starting requests (process 1264).
20130712.143859 W   736 QBNInvoiceAdd::HandleAggregate  unexpected tag 'Memo'.
20130712.143859 E   736 XercesSAXErrorHandler   Unknown element 'InventorySiteLocationRef' -- error at line 19, column 26 in XML data.
20130712.143859 I   736 MsgSetHandler   Parser error, finishing.
20130712.143859 I   736 QBSDKProcessRequest Application named 'IOS Briefcase Sync' finishing requests (process 1264), ret = 1.
20130712.143859 E   1264    RequestProcessor    Process Request error = 80042500, There was an error when parsing the provided XML file.
20130712.143937 I   1264    RequestProcessor    Connection closed by app named 'IOS Briefcase Sync'
20130712.143937 I   1264    RequestProcessor    ========== Ended Connection ==========
```

The client is running Quickbooks Enterprise Solutions Manufacturing and Wholesale Edition 12

I installed QBFC12_0 and QBXMLRP2 using the installers provided with the SDK. A HostQuery returns 11 as the highest supported QBXML major version, and this is the version I use when creating requests.

I did not uninstall QBFC7, which was the version previously in use at this client site, because I wanted the ability to roll back (which I did). Could that be the problem?

Do I need to install or uninstall something else? Would a reboot help? I haven't been able to get anyone at the client site to reboot yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem, in my case, turned out to be that I was using the wrong field. I should have used "InventorySiteRef" rather than "InventorySiteLocationRef," which referes to a bin number within a site. Once I made this correction, everything worked.

The problem with "InventorySiteLocationRef" remains, however. It's a legitimate field in QBFC, and the supposedly all-knowing Onscreen Reference from Intuit does not indicate that it may fail. Fail it does, however, for many if not all versions of QB. I finally found, in the QBFC 12 Release Notes, a rather extensive list of fields that appear to be legitimate, but don't actually work. Here's how Intuit describes them. You can search for this text to find the list in the Release Notes:

**NOTE: A majority of these changes have NOT been implented in Quick-
Books. These are spec changes only to allow for implementation in a future
release of QuickBooks.**

Comment: This was a big help to me.  I appreciate your insight.